# Raydium Liquidity Pool API call && calculation of price

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli, raydium

I have a problem regarding the calculation of a Raydium pool price.
(https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk)

1. Raydium API Request for Liquid Pool V4 SOL/USDC.

```
import { Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4 } from "@raydium-io/raydium-sdk";
import { BN } from "bn.js"

const SOL_USDC_POOL_ID = "58oQChx4yWmvKdwLLZzBi4ChoCc2fqCUWBkwMihLYQo2"; // Your pool ID

async function parsePoolInfo() {
  const connection = new Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com", "recent");
  
  const info = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey(SOL_USDC_POOL_ID));
  if (!info) return;
  
  // Assuming the structure was successfully decoded
  const poolState = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(info.data);

  console.log(poolState)
}


parsePoolInfo();
```

1.1 Console Output of the API call

```
{
  status: <BN: 1>,
  nonce: <BN: fe>,
  maxOrder: <BN: 7>,
  depth: <BN: 3>,
  baseDecimal: <BN: 9>,
  quoteDecimal: <BN: 6>,
  state: <BN: 1>,
  resetFlag: <BN: 1>,
  minSize: <BN: f4240>,
  volMaxCutRatio: <BN: 1f4>,
  amountWaveRatio: <BN: 0>,
  baseLotSize: <BN: f4240>,
  quoteLotSize: <BN: f4240>,
  minPriceMultiplier: <BN: 1>,
  maxPriceMultiplier: <BN: 3b9aca00>,
  systemDecimalValue: <BN: 3b9aca00>,
  minSeparateNumerator: <BN: 5>,
  minSeparateDenominator: <BN: 2710>,
  tradeFeeNumerator: <BN: 19>,
  tradeFeeDenominator: <BN: 2710>,
  pnlNumerator: <BN: c>,
  pnlDenominator: <BN: 64>,
  swapFeeNumerator: <BN: 19>,
  swapFeeDenominator: <BN: 2710>,
  baseNeedTakePnl: <BN: 15c0b6d20>,
  quoteNeedTakePnl: <BN: 3f148c03>,
  quoteTotalPnl: <BN: cc322d0c31>,
  baseTotalPnl: <BN: 20f2cc8a6d10>,
  poolOpenTime: <BN: 0>,
  punishPcAmount: <BN: 0>,
  punishCoinAmount: <BN: 0>,
  orderbookToInitTime: <BN: 0>,
  swapBaseInAmount: <BN: 198ae479152985>,
  swapQuoteOutAmount: <BN: daf1151a5f2b>,
  swapBase2QuoteFee: <BN: 92b08e7d17>,
  swapQuoteInAmount: <BN: e533d56efeeb>,
  swapBaseOutAmount: <BN: 1a4bba4d1f08f5>,
  swapQuote2BaseFee: <BN: 1058e429cf81>,
  baseVault: PublicKey [PublicKey(DQyrAcCrDXQ7NeoqGgDCZwBvWDcYmFCjSb9JtteuvPpz)] {
    _bn: <BN: b870e12dd379891561d2e9fa8f26431834eb736f2f24fc2a2a4dff1fd5dca4df>
  },
  quoteVault: PublicKey [PublicKey(HLmqeL62xR1QoZ1HKKbXRrdN1p3phKpxRMb2VVopvBBz)] {
    _bn: <BN: f2cbb9b760eddb185706303063ad33d7b57296ea02d4e0335e31ceafa4cc42dd>
  },
  baseMint: PublicKey [PublicKey(So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112)] {
    _bn: <BN: 69b8857feab8184fb687f634618c035dac439dc1aeb3b5598a0f00000000001>
  },
  quoteMint: PublicKey [PublicKey(EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v)] {
    _bn: <BN: c6fa7af3bedbad3a3d65f36aabc97431b1bbe4c2d2f6e0e47ca60203452f5d61>
  },
  lpMint: PublicKey [PublicKey(8HoQnePLqPj4M7PUDzfw8e3Ymdwgc7NLGnaTUapubyvu)] {
    _bn: <BN: 6c4f93d858e88ffafea08c43674497e8e6a932c0c83148262a1ae3ccc7829ec6>
  },
  openOrders: PublicKey [PublicKey(HmiHHzq4Fym9e1D4qzLS6LDDM3tNsCTBPDWHTLZ763jY)] {
    _bn: <BN: f92f390ff9609e8ad437bb8e4c1f1aa43ac05d24308cca77de8512c5509292d3>
  },
  marketId: PublicKey [PublicKey(8BnEgHoWFysVcuFFX7QztDmzuH8r5ZFvyP3sYwn1XTh6)] {
    _bn: <BN: 6ac4c3cefa9f19bf54c8dc0f5e4d1ceee5327d26482b29d2b13cbaa43447218d>
  },
  marketProgramId: PublicKey [PublicKey(srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX)] {
    _bn: <BN: d0751a8282da61305fe299c37b998e58471db1135037310f8be1045a60af6ee>
  },
  targetOrders: PublicKey [PublicKey(CZza3Ej4Mc58MnxWA385itCC9jCo3L1D7zc3LKy1bZMR)] {
    _bn: <BN: abe43c7c1e21eaa6f97c8bd355e21bd1279674756c1c8e106c6e712ba116d970>
  },
  withdrawQueue: PublicKey [PublicKey(11111111111111111111111111111111)] {
    _bn: <BN: 0>
  },
  lpVault: PublicKey [PublicKey(11111111111111111111111111111111)] {
    _bn: <BN: 0>
  },
  owner: PublicKey [PublicKey(GThUX1Atko4tqhN2NaiTazWSeFWMuiUvfFnyJyUghFMJ)] {
    _bn: <BN: e5b62b65cb3bbda6f56888e66fee8e64dc5560199c0f88b11fe273bd059e8aa1>
  },
  lpReserve: <BN: 41e692e5f338>,
  padding: [ <BN: 700dc7>, <BN: 0>, <BN: 0> ]
}
```

2. Decode API DATA BigNumbers into decimals.

```
  console.log("Status:", poolState.status.toNumber());
  console.log("Nonce:", poolState.nonce.toNumber());
  console.log("Max Order:", poolState.maxOrder.toNumber());
  console.log("Depth:", poolState.depth.toNumber());
  console.log("Base Decimal:", poolState.baseDecimal.toNumber());
  console.log("Quote Decimal:", poolState.quoteDecimal.toNumber());
  console.log("State:", poolState.state.toNumber());
  console.log("Reset Flag:", poolState.resetFlag.toNumber());
  console.log("Min Size:", poolState.minSize.toNumber());
  console.log("Vol Max Cut Ratio:", poolState.volMaxCutRatio.toNumber());
  console.log("Amount Wave Ratio:", poolState.amountWaveRatio.toNumber());
  console.log("Base Lot Size:", poolState.baseLotSize.toNumber());
  console.log("Quote Lot Size:", poolState.quoteLotSize.toNumber());
  console.log("Min Price Multiplier:", poolState.minPriceMultiplier.toNumber());
  console.log("Max Price Multiplier:", poolState.maxPriceMultiplier.toNumber());
  console.log("System Decimal Value:", poolState.systemDecimalValue.toNumber());
  console.log("Min Separate Numerator:", poolState.minSeparateNumerator.toNumber());
  console.log("Min Separate Denominator:", poolState.minSeparateDenominator.toNumber());
  console.log("Trade Fee Numerator:", poolState.tradeFeeNumerator.toNumber());
  console.log("Trade Fee Denominator:", poolState.tradeFeeDenominator.toNumber());
  console.log("PnL Numerator:", poolState.pnlNumerator.toNumber());
  console.log("PnL Denominator:", poolState.pnlDenominator.toNumber());
  console.log("Swap Fee Numerator:", poolState.swapFeeNumerator.toNumber());
  console.log("Swap Fee Denominator:", poolState.swapFeeDenominator.toNumber());
  console.log("Base Need Take PnL:", poolState.baseNeedTakePnl.toNumber());
  console.log("Quote Need Take PnL:", poolState.quoteNeedTakePnl.toNumber());
  console.log("Quote Total PnL:", poolState.quoteTotalPnl.toNumber());
  console.log("Base Total PnL:", poolState.baseTotalPnl.toNumber());
  console.log("Pool Open Time:", poolState.poolOpenTime.toNumber());
  console.log("Punish Pc Amount:", poolState.punishPcAmount.toNumber());
  console.log("Punish Coin Amount:", poolState.punishCoinAmount.toNumber());
  console.log("Orderbook To Init Time:", poolState.orderbookToInitTime.toNumber());
  console.log("Swap Base In Amount:", poolState.swapBaseInAmount.toNumber());
  console.log("Swap Quote Out Amount:", poolState.swapQuoteOutAmount.toNumber());
  console.log("Swap Base2Quote Fee:", poolState.swapBase2QuoteFee.toNumber());
  console.log("Swap Quote In Amount:", poolState.swapQuoteInAmount.toNumber());
  console.log("Swap Base Out Amount:", poolState.swapBaseOutAmount.toNumber());
  console.log("Swap Quote2Base Fee:", poolState.swapQuote2BaseFee.toNumber());

  // For PublicKey fields, you can directly log them as they are:
  console.log("Base Vault:", poolState.baseVault.toString());
  console.log("Quote Vault:", poolState.quoteVault.toString());
  console.log("Base Mint:", poolState.baseMint.toString());
  console.log("Quote Mint:", poolState.quoteMint.toString());
  console.log("LP Mint:", poolState.lpMint.toString());
  console.log("Open Orders:", poolState.openOrders.toString());
  console.log("Market ID:", poolState.marketId.toString());
  console.log("Market Program ID:", poolState.marketProgramId.toString());
  console.log("Target Orders:", poolState.targetOrders.toString());
  console.log("Withdraw Queue:", poolState.withdrawQueue.toString());
  console.log("LP Vault:", poolState.lpVault.toString());
  console.log("Owner:", poolState.owner.toString());
  console.log("LP Reserve:", poolState.lpReserve.toNumber());
```

2.2 Console Output decoded BigNumbers in decimals

```
Status: 1
Nonce: 254
Max Order: 7
Depth: 3
Base Decimal: 9
Quote Decimal: 6
State: 1
Reset Flag: 1
Min Size: 1000000
Vol Max Cut Ratio: 500
Amount Wave Ratio: 0
Base Lot Size: 1000000
Quote Lot Size: 1000000
Min Price Multiplier: 1
Max Price Multiplier: 1000000000
System Decimal Value: 1000000000
Min Separate Numerator: 5
Min Separate Denominator: 10000
Trade Fee Numerator: 25
Trade Fee Denominator: 10000
PnL Numerator: 12
PnL Denominator: 100
Swap Fee Numerator: 25
Swap Fee Denominator: 10000
Base Need Take PnL: 5839220000
Quote Need Take PnL: 1058311171
Quote Total PnL: 877015141425
Base Total PnL: 36227185798416
Pool Open Time: 0
Punish Pc Amount: 0
Punish Coin Amount: 0
Orderbook To Init Time: 0
Swap Base In Amount: 7189588306372997
Swap Quote Out Amount: 240728976023339
Swap Base2Quote Fee: 630027353367
Swap Quote In Amount: 252010786914027
Swap Base Out Amount: 7401612924356853
Swap Quote2Base Fee: 17973971111809
Base Vault: DQyrAcCrDXQ7NeoqGgDCZwBvWDcYmFCjSb9JtteuvPpz
Quote Vault: HLmqeL62xR1QoZ1HKKbXRrdN1p3phKpxRMb2VVopvBBz
Base Mint: So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112
Quote Mint: EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v
LP Mint: 8HoQnePLqPj4M7PUDzfw8e3Ymdwgc7NLGnaTUapubyvu
Open Orders: HmiHHzq4Fym9e1D4qzLS6LDDM3tNsCTBPDWHTLZ763jY
Market ID: 8BnEgHoWFysVcuFFX7QztDmzuH8r5ZFvyP3sYwn1XTh6
Market Program ID: srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX
Target Orders: CZza3Ej4Mc58MnxWA385itCC9jCo3L1D7zc3LKy1bZMR
Withdraw Queue: 11111111111111111111111111111111
LP Vault: 11111111111111111111111111111111
Owner: GThUX1Atko4tqhN2NaiTazWSeFWMuiUvfFnyJyUghFMJ
LP Reserve: 72458562827064
```

**Here is where I struggle**
3. Calculation of the Price of one SOL. ( 1 SOL / (X) USDC )

```
**//ATTEMP NUMBER 1:**

// Just for clarification where I got these values!

// from decoded data: Swap Quote Out Amount: 240728976023339, Swap Base Out Amount: 7401612924356853

function calculatePricePerSOLInUSDC(): string {
    return (Number(BigInt("252010786914027")) / Math.pow(10, 6) / (Number(BigInt("7401612924356853")) / Math.pow(10, 9))).toFixed(6);
  }
  
  console.log(`Price per 1 SOL in USDC: ${calculatePricePerSOLInUSDC()}`);


**//ATTEMPT 2**
//Standard calculation of quote amount / base amount
// Got values of these two "VAULTS"
//Base Vault: DQyrAcCrDXQ7NeoqGgDCZwBvWDcYmFCjSb9JtteuvPpz
//Quote Vault: HLmqeL62xR1QoZ1HKKbXRrdN1p3phKpxRMb2VVopvBBz

// at the current timestamp the values are:
//23,177.61 SOL
//5,700,097.46 USDC

5700097.46 / 23177.61 = 245,931
```

3.1 Output of Calculation (which obviously can´t be right)

```
**ATTEMPT 1* Price per 1 SOL in USDC: 34.048091
**ATTEMPT 2* Price per 1 SOl in USDC: 245,931
```

**If any additional information is needed please feel free to leave a comment!**

Answer (score 1):

This Hybrid AMM pool is sharing idle liquidity with OpenBook, the value in the base and quote vault doesn't account for the orders in the event q of the CLOB.

Divergences between quoteVault and real quote amount can occur.

> pool_vault_amount = amm_vault_amount + open_orders.native_coin_total +  part_filled_amount - need_take_pnl_coin

You can refer to this program to calculate the amounts in event_q: https://github.com/openbook-dex/program/blob/master/dex/src/state.rs#L2975

Not certain how to interpret, the 34$ result though.